# Downloading images from server and applying them as background for dynamically created buttons

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-button

Scenario : I have to download the images from server and set them as background for dynamically created buttons. Number of images keep changing, so I have to create that many number of buttons dynamically.

What I have completed so far : I successfully managed to download the images using AsyncTask and set them as background for dynamically created buttons. If there is no internet connection or if images are not downloaded for some reason then setting the background of each buttons to some default image.

Problem : Everything works so fine on phone, i.e downloading images and creating buttons dynamically depending upon the number of images and setting images as background for them. Now when I run the same program on Tablet it is not working. Buttons are not getting generated dynamically. But if I turn of the internet connection and then run, wonder happens.! Everything works fine i.e buttons are dynamically generated with the default image as their background. I'm not able to understand why is it so.! Is there any problem with AsyncTask? Any help will be appreciated..

Here is the AsyncTask

```
 public class GetsImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

FileCache fileCache;
ProgressDialog pd;
String url;
GetImages task = null;
Context context;
private Bitmap image;
HomeDynamic activity;
AsyncImage responseImage = null;

public GetImages(String url, HomeDynamic activity) {
    this.url = url;
    // this.context = context;
    this.responseImage = activity;
    attach(activity);
    fileCache = new FileCache(activity);
    //pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
}

public GetImages(Context context) {

    this.context = context;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    /*pd.setTitle("Processing");
    pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.show();*/
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    /*if (pd.isShowing())
        pd.dismiss();*/
    // studentPic.setImageBitmap(result);
    responseImage.processImage(result);

}

public void detach() {
    activity = null;
}

public void attach(HomeDynamic activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    final int buffer_size = 1024;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
        for (;;) {
            int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {

        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 64;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new 
                     FileInputStream(f), null,   o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without showing any code that you did, it is very difficult to figure out where the problem is. If your activity involves so many photos, I suggest using Picasso library which will do excellent job for handling images.

Comment: Thanks to everyone whoever read my very long question. I just added the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. And it is working fine now. :)